# Download Supplier Transactions

Tags: netsuite

I am asked to see if we can download data from the ‘Supplier Transactions’ tab on the supplier. I checked for the same but could not enable the option to download this data. Then I tried to replicate the same with a saved search. However, I am not able to get the correct fields for ‘source transaction’ and ‘Original Transaction’ fields.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add the applied to transaction and applying transaction